# Serialization of polymorphic objects

Tags: java, serialization

I have classes `Osoba`(Person) and `Zawodnik`(Constestant)

`Contestant` extends `Person` and `Person` implements `Serializable`. Does `Constestant` automatically implements `Serializable` too? I think so.

The extension (`ArrayList ekstensja`) of class `Person` contains objects of different classes extending class `Person`. Will the method `zapiszEkstensje()` in the `Person` class work correctly? I think so.

Example:

```
public abstract class Osoba implements Serializable {
/....something..../

    private static ArrayList<Osoba> ekstensja = new ArrayList<Osoba>();

    private void dodajZawodnik(Osoba osoba) {
        ekstensja.add(osoba);
    }

    private void usunZawodnik(Osoba osoba) {
        ekstensja.remove(osoba);
    }

    public static void pokazEkstensje() {
        for (Osoba zawodnik : ekstensja)
            System.out.println(zawodnik + "\n");

    }

    public static void zapiszEkstensje() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("osoba.ser"));                                                
            outputStream.writeObject(ekstensja); 
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void wczytajEkstensje(){
        try {
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("osoba.ser"));                                                
            ekstensja = (ArrayList<Osoba>) (inputStream.readObject()); 
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

---

```
public class Zawodnik extends Osoba  {  }
// DO I NEED TO MAKE THIS CLASS IMPLEMENT SERIALIZABLE TOO?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to java doc of [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface, all the subtypes of a serializable class  are themselves serializable.

So, the answer is yes, if `Person` implements `Serializable` all its children will be serializable.